# Editing Android contacts on a pc

Tags: contacts

I'm asking about editing Android contact files on Windows. What software can I use to edit and create them? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the extension of your Android contact files?

Comment: It's extension is .vcf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [VCF Manager for Windows](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/app-vcf-manager-v1-0-beta-t3636232) from XDA Developers.